# Is there a way to structureClone almost an entire structure and not damage the source object?

Tags: javascript

Given an object `obj` with a bunch of properties (which themselves can be objects, etc) then I know I can use the recent `structuredClone(obj)` to make a deep copy. In my case though, `obj.x` and `obj.y` are large and I dont want to copy them. Indeed, the whole purpose of the deep copy is to get ready for a new set of data to get loaded into `x` and `y`.

I know I could do this "fast" by transferring `x` and `y` which would at least avoid their getting copied, but it would trash the original `obj`.

I also don't want to list all of the properties by hand in the source code (I wont know them until run time).

Is there a way to write something like this:

```
var newobj = structuredClone(obj, butskip=[obj.x, obj.y]);
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could probably try something like this:

```js
var newobj = structuredClone({
    ...obj,
    x: null,
    y: null
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
function partialClone({x, y, ...rest}) {
  return {x, y, ...structuredClone(rest)}
}

console.log(partialClone({x:1,y:2,z:3}))
```

or, with an IIFE:

```js
console.log((({x, y, ...rest})=>
  ({x, y, ...structuredClone(rest)}))({x:1,y:2,z:3}))
```

Comment: That's just insane. :-)    I had seen the three dots before but didnt know how to use them. Thanks!

Comment: the three dots is the javascript spread operator. It's like a copy opration to parr every entry from one object or array to another object or array. At the moment i am not sure if they are a referenz copy or a new value so the structure clone will cover that you will end with a real independent copy of your original value